# ORACLE PL/SQL: Calling an external Oracle PL/SQL procedure with maximum execution time

Tags: oracle, time, max, procedure, execution

Please suppose that in my Oracle database (release 12) I have an Oracle PL/SQL procedure, called A.

This procedure "A" calls the procedure "B" (we can see it as a "black box", this means it is not modifyable) stored in external Oracle database reachable through a database link.

How can we limit the execution time of the B procedure?

The goal is to execute B for maximum 10 minutes, for example, after then, return to procedure A and continue execution.

Please assume that you cannot modify the B Oracle PL/SQL procedure.

Any clues?

Thank you very much for considering my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use DBMS_SCHEDULER to create a JOB which you can stop/kill. Just check out the documentation for [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034)